# Is there some way I can introduce a delay into my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function in my code. Here's a simplified version:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $form.attr('action'),
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $form.serializeArray(),
  success: function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    // delay here
    alert("hello");
  }
```

Is there some way that I can introduce a delay. For example a delay of 5 seconds into the above code?

Note that I need to replace the words // delay here with something that can give a delay if possible.

Comment: Checkout the setTimeout function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` with an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() { /* your code here */ }, 5000);
```

This will run the code within that function after a 5-second delay.

Comment: OP expectation on delay may be is for subsequent piece of code. You probably need to mention it there.

Comment: Yes it's for the subsequent code. I want to replace the words // delay here with something.

Comment: I don't follow... just put whatever code you want to be delayed within `/* your code here */` in my example.  In your example, that would be `alert("hello");`.  Does this not answer your question?

Comment: Marie: there is no sleep() that just waits 5 seconds and then continues executing the function. There is only the setTimeout, that executes the code after x milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $form.serializeArray(),
            success: function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                  // delay here
                  setTimeout(function() { alert("hello"); }, 5000);
            });
```

Comment: but can I just do something like an empty function? The above is just an example so I want to replace the words // delay here with something.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `setTimeout()` and this is how you would introduce it into your own code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $form.attr('action'),
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $form.serializeArray(),
  success: function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    // save 'this' pointer in case you need it in the setTimeout() function
    // because it will be set to something different in the setTimeout() callback
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // execute whatever code you want here with a 5 second delay
        alert("hello");
    }, 5000) ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method

if you want to delay the alert just use

```
success: function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                  // delay here
                  setTimeout(function(){alert("hello");}, 5000); // 5000 is in milliseconds
            }
```